# Error in mSVM-RFE model empty

Tags: r, svm

I am trying mSVM-RFE tool to feature selection for my data, my input data matrix is tab separated and first column is class, other columns are genes name (50*100).

```
library(e1071)
source('msvmRFE.R')
input <- read.table("input.txt",  header=T, sep="\t")
svmRFE(input, k=10, halve.above=100)
```

this is error

```
 svmRFE(input, k=10, halve.above=100)
Scaling data...Done!
  0%Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : 
  Model is empty!
```

Please help me what is error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but perhaps I can help others.

Please, try:

1. Check if your outcomes are numbered factors, such as: 1 and 2. Also, I believe you can't use more than two classes for mSVM-RFE.
2. mSVM-RFE won't handle NAs;
3. How many observations do you have for each class? Are they asymmetrical?